# How to use a SHA256 MessageDigest in Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, exception, debian

I encountered a problem while trying to get my java project running on my Debian 10 server.
Everything seems to work, but java throws an error when i try to get an instance of a MessageDigest with "SHA256".

It occurs in this line:

`MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256");`

The exception:

`java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256 MessageDigest not available`

Is there a way to install SHA256 functionality or another way i can create a sha256 hash?

Comment: Try `SHA-256` instead (with a hyphen). See a list for Java 8 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest). And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#messagedigest-algorithms) for Java 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
```

and to list all available:

```
Set<String> messageDigest = Security.getAlgorithms("MessageDigest");
messageDigest.forEach(System.out::println);
```